# Why does the regressor '1/t' in y(t) = B1 + B2(1/t) + u tend to zero?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, law-of-large-numbers, large-deviation-theory

My textbook says that if n tends to infinity then each observation provides less and less information about B2. This happens due to the fact that (1/t) tends to zero and hence varies less and less across observations as t becomes larger. Can someone explain this?

Comment: There are some missing bits for non experts: who is $n$? What is the context?

Comment: my bad. "n" is like the number of samples from a population. "t" and "n" are thus the same. You can say n = 500 and hence t = 1/500.

Comment: I really don't understand the part starting from hence varies less ....

Comment: It sounds a lot like observing that the difference between $\frac1n$ and $\frac 1{n+1}$ gets closer and closer to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. In other words, an increase of $n$ by $1$ will have less effect on $\frac 1n$ as $n$ gets larger.